# Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/material.dart:34:1: Error: Error when reading '/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

export 'src/material/bottom_app_bar.dart';
^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

any help would mean so much to me.

I tried the flutter clean command but it didn't work